# Unix sort function doesn't completely sort string with numbers

Tags: sort

I have a file that contains two columns separated by tab.

```
  A10         A10_motorway_(Switzerland)              
  A-10        A-10_N/AW
  A10         A10_Networks
  A-10        A-10_road
  A10         A10_road                  
  A10_road_(California)      A10_road_(Canada)      
  A10_road_(Croatia)         A10_road_(disambiguation)  
  A10_road_(England)         A10_road_(Great_Britain)   
  A10_road_(Isle_of_Man)     A10_road_(Isle_of_Man) 
  A10_road_(Latvia)          A10_road_(Malaysia)
  A10_road_(United_Kingdom)  A10_road_(United_States_of_America)    
  A10_road_(USA)             A10_road_(Zimbabwe)
  A-10        A-10_Shrike
  A10         A10_(Switzerland)
```

I want to sort this file by the first column in alphabetical order. So the same titles should appear consecutively.

So I did this:

```
     sort -t $'\t' -k1 -d filename
```

But the result is actually the snapshot above. As you see, entries "A-10" are not ordered and do not happen consecutively. I don't really care about the alphabetical order per se, but I want the same titles occurring consecutively. Could anyone explain why sort doesn't allow me to do this and how to fix this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found empirically that `-k1,1` puts the "`A10`"s together, and the "`A-10`"s together, but I don't understand why.
This is with `sort` from GNU coreutils 8.4.

Comment: there's no mystery to it if you read up the `sort` man page

Comment: I did. What did I miss?

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
LC_COLLATE=C sort myfile
```

encountered similar behavior in the past and this one suggested by a coworker helped me